# Отладка исходных кодов .Net Framework в Visual Studio

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, intellij-idea, отладка

Например, при разработке и в процессе отладке java кода в idea можно проваливаться во внутреннюю реализацию пакетов и классов JDK.
Есть ли что-то подобное при разработке и отладке c# в Visual Studio?

Например, как при отладке зайти в метод `XmlReader.Create`:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("shema.xsd");
```

Comment: Возможно, поможет [это](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42693502/6468198)

Comment: [How to: Debug .NET Framework source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source?view=vs-2019)